# Finding names in templatized base classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, base-class, name-lookup

I'm reading Effective C++ 3rd Edition, item 43 "Know how to access names in templatized base classes".

```
template<typename T>
class B {
    T i;
};

template<typename T>
class D: public B<T> {
public:
    void Foo() {
        T a = B<T>::i;
    }
};

int main() {
    D<int> d;
}
```

For the above codes, I know if the `B<T>::` is not added before `i` in `D::Foo()`, compilers will complain "`i` was not declared in this scope". (But it didn't complain `i` is private in `B`.)

However, if `T i;` is not declared in B, like the following, the compiling goes well.

```
template<typename T>
class B {
};

template<typename T>
class D: public B<T> {
public:
    void Foo() {
        T a = B<T>::i;
    }
};

int main() {
    D<int> d;
}
```

Compilers are defaulted not to find names in templatized base classes.
But why they still don't do even I told them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why they still don't do even I told them?

Because the member function `Foo` is not used, then it's not [instantiated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation) at all.

> This applies to the members of the class template: unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated, and does not require a definition.

You might get an [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I2y4sKLGv3zlXePF) if `Foo` is called, like

```
D<int> d;
d.Foo();
```

BTW

> But it didn't complain `i` is private in `B`.

Because accessibility check is performed after name lookup. The name `i` is not found, then accessibility of nothing could be checked.